# RichTextField - creates <p> ... </p>

Tags: wagtail

(wagtail 1.9) I created a RichTextField (role in class person) and a FieldPanel for this field. In the template is {{ person.role }} . wagtail generates "<p>*the role text*</p>".

When does wagtail create <p>  ... </p> for a RichTextField?

Answer (score 6):

You should use the `|richtext` filter when outputting rich text content in templates:

```
{% load wagtailadmin_tags %}

...
   {{ person.role|richtext }}
```

(This is necessary because rich text data is stored internally as a non-HTML format, which preserves references to other Wagtail pages and objects, e.g. `<a linktype="page" id="123">some other page</a>`. The `|richtext` filter converts this to "true" HTML.)

Comment: I did this in a template - it works. I did the same in an other template and get a TemplateSyntaxError:   

Invalid filter: 'richtext'   ( I didn't forget to load the wagtailadmin_tags)

Comment: A missing or broken `load` line is the only thing I can think of which would cause the error "Invalid filter: 'richtext'". Please double-check your code for typos (including the `{% .. %}` brackets - if those aren't correct the tag will be ignored).

Comment: I don't know which version are you using but richtext filter should be load from wagtailcore_tags instead of  wagtailadmin_tags. Example: `{% load wagtailcore_tags %}`